# Type 1 hypervisor using binary translation

Tags: virtualization, hypervisor

Is there any papers or projects proposing or fulfilling a type 1 hypervisor using binary translation to support OS compiled for different architecture?

Comment: I don’t think anyone would call such a thing a hypervisor.

Comment: directly running qemu alike software on hardware, and heterogeneous OS running on top of this software layer, like a type 1 hypervisor on some level @prl